# What is the origin of magic number 42, indispensable in coding?

Tags: language-agnostic, coding-style

**Update:**
Surprised that it is being so heavily downvoted...

The question is **coding-related** and before asking this question I have googled for "42" in combination with:

- **site:msdn.micrsoft.com**
- "code example"
- "c#"
- "magic number"

And I am not an expert/fan of Western culture/literature.

Also found, [Why are variables “i” and “j” used for counters? [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4137785/why-are-variables-i-and-j-used-for-counters/4137809#4137809) which was not closed but even protected.

---

I feel that everybody knows it, except me...

What is the origin of ubiquitous magic digit 42 used all over the code samples and samples?

How have you come using 42?  because I have not ever come or ever used **42**

After some search, I found MSDN doc on it:  [Magic Numbers: Integers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee621251.aspx):

- **"Aside from a book/movie reference, developers often use this as an arbitrary value"**

Well, this did not explain me anything.

Which movies and books have I missed for all those years of being involved  in development, coding and programming and around-IT related activities like rwquirements analysis, system administration, etc??

## Some references to some texts using code snippets with 42 (just C#-related):

Jérôme Laban. [C# Async Tips and Tricks, Part 3: Tasks and the Synchronization Context](http://www.jaylee.org/post/2012/09/29/C-Async-Tips-and-Tricks-Part-3-Tasks-and-the-Synchronization-Context.aspx)

```
  var t = Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
              .ContinueWith
                (
                    _ => Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(42))
                );
```

MSDN [Asynchronous Agents Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492627.aspx)

```
   send(_target, 42);
```

[Quickstart: Calling asynchronous APIs in C# or Visual Basic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj220067.aspx)

```
  Office.context.document.setSelectedDataAsync(
      "<html><body>hello world</body></html>",
       {coercionType: "html", asyncContext: 42},
       function(asyncResult) {
           write(asyncResult.status + " " + asyncResult.asyncContext);
```

[Asynchronous Programming in C++ Using PPL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh781020.aspx)

```
  task<int> myTask = someOtherTask.then([]() { return 42; });
```

[Boxing and Unboxing (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx)

```
  Console.WriteLine(String.Concat("Answer", 42, true));
```

[How To: Override the ToString Method (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173154%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

```
  int x = 42;
```

[Trace Listeners](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983739%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

```
  // Use this example when debugging.
  System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Error in Widget 42");
  // Use this example when tracing.
  System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("Error in Widget 42");
```

[|| Operator (C# Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/6373h346.aspx)

```
  // The following line displays True, because 42 is evenly  
  // divisible by 7.
  Console.WriteLine("Divisible returns {0}.", Divisible(42, 7));

  // The following line displays False, because 42 is not evenly 
  // divisible by 5.
  Console.WriteLine("Divisible returns {0}.", Divisible(42, 5));

  // The following line displays False when method Divisible  
  // uses ||, because you cannot divide by 0. 
  // If method Divisible uses | instead of ||, this line 
  // causes an exception.
  Console.WriteLine("Divisible returns {0}.", Divisible(42, 0));
```

WIKIPedia [C Sharp (programming language)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_%28programming_language%29)

```
  int foo = 42;         // Value type.
```

Comment: I'd tell you but then I'd have to kill you...

Comment: +1 for best question ever :D

Comment: I got that strange feeling that this question does not belong here, but I'm not sure about where moving it to...

Comment: @JoeriHendrickx How is this a good question? It's off topic and I doubt the veracity of the prior research. A Google for "magic number 42" retrieves the answer quite easily.

Comment: Ask Eccentrica Gallumbits.

Comment: And the answer is ... 42 :)

Comment: @DuncanJones just made me actually laugh out loud :)  I know that you're completely right, but for this one I just have to let it slide.

Comment: "And I am not an expert/fan of Western culture/literature." - That is OK, but "The Hitch Hiker's Guide to the Galaxy" is a highly recommended read either way :)

Comment: @valex But what is the question?

Comment: @RossPatterson, my question, as I've put it there, was: "How have you come (or started) to use 42 in your coding?"

Comment: A bit late to the party but if you actually read the lock reason in [Why are variables “i” and “j” used for counters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4137785/why-are-variables-i-and-j-used-for-counters/4137809) you'll see it says *"This question exists because it has historical significance, but it is not considered a good, on-topic question for this site, so **please do not use it as evidence that you can ask similar questions here.**"*

Comment: @Juhana, what are [etimology](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/etymology) and [history](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/history) tags good for?

Comment: I think it worth to be noted that according to the New Testament(Matthew 1) quantity of generations from Abraham to Jesus Christ also equals to 42.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The answer is, as people already have stated, [The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy).

I made a little experiment and put a couple of numbers in the search field, and these are the results:

[image]

It seems like 42 beats its neighbors clearly, but it can't touch regular numbers like 40, 45 and 50, no matter how magical it is.

It would be interesting to do the same search in *source code only*.

Comment: "50" is over-used because it is related with fifty-fifty (stats, gambling), coins, etc. but unrelated to coding styling

Comment: "0" gives 1,892,567 results and "1" 2,354,125 ;)

Comment: I love "117". Love is blind and unreasonable

Comment: @ Victor Sand, feeling that I am exposing my illiteracy but what have you used to generate the diagram?

Comment: @ГеннадийВанинНовосибирск, I just put the numbers in an Excel spreadsheet and used the standard graph tools.

Answer (score 32):

It's from [The Hitch Hiker's Guide to the Galaxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy).

> In The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy (published in 1979), the
>   characters visit the legendary planet Magrathea, home to the
>   now-collapsed planet-building industry, and meet Slartibartfast, a
>   planetary coastline designer who was responsible for the fjords of
>   Norway. Through archival recordings, he relates the story of a race of
>   hyper-intelligent pan-dimensional beings who built a computer named
>   Deep Thought to calculate the Answer to the Ultimate Question of Life,
>   the Universe, and Everything. When the answer was revealed to be 42,
>   Deep Thought explained that the answer was incomprehensible because
>   the beings didn't know what they were asking. It went on to predict
>   that another computer, more powerful than itself would be made and
>   designed by it to calculate the question for the answer. (Later on,
>   referencing this, Adams would create the 42 Puzzle, a puzzle which
>   could be approached in multiple ways, all yielding the answer 42.)

Comment: For bonus points ... _why_ did Douglas Adams choose 42?

Comment: @PaulCager: [I sat at my desk,
stared into the garden and thought '42 will do' I typed it out.](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/alt.fan.douglas-adams/595nPukE-Jo/koaAJ3tPBtEJ)

Comment: So, "42", as it was put in [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee621251.aspx) is synonym of "arbitrary value". I always thought before that "arbitrary" was synonym to "random" and have nothing to do with "pre-chosen", "fixed" or **"ULTIMATE"r**

Comment: "Arbitrary" and "random" are completely different concepts that should never ever be confused.

Comment: I thought it was 6 × 9

Comment: @Kirby think again now that you are 5 years older.

Comment: @YSC Is it certain "42" is base 10? It could be base 13 and Kirby would be right...

Comment: Yes it is. See Andomar's comment.

Answer (score 10):

Dude!

It's the Answer to the Ultimate Question of Life, the Universe, and Everything! As computed by Deep Thought supercomputer, which took 7.5 million years!

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_answer_to_life_the_universe_and_everything#Answer_to_the_Ultimate_Question_of_Life.2C_the_Universe_and_Everything_.2842.29

Answer (score 8):

Check [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Answer_to_The_Ultimate_Question_of_Life,_the_Universe,_and_Everything#Answer_to_the_Ultimate_Question_of_Life.2C_the_Universe.2C_and_Everything_.2842.29) out. 42 is the `ultimate answer to the ultimate question of life the universe and everything`

Answer (score 4):

This is from **The Hitch hikers Guide to the Galaxy** and is:

> The Answer to the Ultimate Question of Life, the Universe, and Everything

[WikiLink](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrases_from_The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy)

Answer (score 4):

Refer [The Hitch Hiker's Guide to the Galaxy.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy)