# Can you write 'for' two times?

Tags: javascript

I've been trying to create list of months where **id** of every months has id written from **months_id**...

```
var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]
var months_id = ["01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12"]
var cells = "";

for (i = 0; i <= 11; i++) {
        cells += "<div id='" + months_id + "'>" + months[i] + "</div>";
}
document.getElementsByClassName("divMonths")[0].innerHTML = cells;
```

I've tried `for (i = 0 && months_id = 0; i <= 11 && months_id <= 0; i++ && months_id++)`

and `for (i = 0; i <= 11; i++) {
        for (months_id = 0; months_id <= 11; months_id++) {//...}
     }`

but both methods didn't work.

Is there any way how to write it correctly?

Comment: What was wrong with your second approach? What errors did you get? Please describe in detail what you mean by "didn't work". And think about whether using the same variable name in the same scope is a good idea or not.

Comment: In your 2nd approach what do you think would happen to the value of `i` in the inner loop and how do you think that could influence the outer loop?

Comment: Yes: `for` `for`

Comment: @Igor Sorry, I meant **months_id** instead of **i**. It's updated.

Comment: Notice that you define `months_id` as an array but are using it as a number.  Does that help you spot the bug?

Comment: Why do you need two for loops? Just one loop can let you write the correct month and month_id to your element's innerHTML. Also, months_id in the loop at the top should be months_id[i]

Comment: @ecg8 I know I can have just one loop but I need the id to be a double digit number. That's the problem.

Comment: @mason Every month was written 12 times. (12× January, 12× February, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

This is your problem:

```
var months_id = //...
//...
for (months_id = 0; months_id <= 11; months_id++) {//...}
```

You're using `months_id` twice in the same scope for two different variables. In other words, there is no way for the program to identify if your `months_id` in the inner loop (the "second for"... *inner for*, you see?) is referring to your array or to the iterator variable.

Your second approach is correct, but you must rename either the array or the inner iterator. Usually, `i`, `j` and `k` are used as iterator variables. Take a look [at this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/86904/why-do-most-of-us-use-i-as-a-loop-counter-variable) for further information. Long story short, your code should go like this:

```
for (i = 0; i <= 11; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j <= 11; j++) {//...}
//...
}
```

Not really sure what you're trying to do here, but that's the correct syntax for **nested loops**, which is what your question refers to.

**Edit:** if you dig reading about why you should name your iterator variables like that, [this answer gets quite creative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4137785/why-are-variables-i-and-j-used-for-counters/)

Answer (score -2):

You need to create a div in which you are writing the variable 'cells'.

```
var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]
var months_id = ["01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12"]
var cells = "";
document.writeln("<div class='divMonths'></div>")
for (i = 0; i <= 11; i++) {
        cells += "<div id='" + months_id + "'>" + months[i] + "</div>";
        //document.writeln(months[i])
}
document.getElementsByClassName("divMonths")[0].innerHTML = cells;
```